# Problems with sessions in OSCommerce

Tags: oscommerce

We encounter strange problem in our OSCommerce site. Sometimes if we go to another page in our site, the users keeps redirected to login.php

Comment: You're going to have to give a bit more information than that. Where do you store the authentication details (session, cookies, etc.)? How are you checking whether the user is authenticated or needs to be redirected to login page? What do the variables look like during debug on one of these cases?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out this one. What I did was I set in OSCommerce admin in the Session Directory to /tmp and I made the define('STORE_SESSIONS', ''); like that. I'm not really sure if this is a stable fix.

Comment: Still the same issue. Sometimes it will keep redirecting to domainhere/login.php

Comment: problem occurs in site or admin section?

Answer (score 0):

Check your cookie settings in includes/configuration.php